# Counting populating rows in Excel, but excluding first row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count the number of populated rows in Excel, but excluding the first row as this is used as a header. ie. I want to start counting from the second row.

The following works to count populated rows, including the first row:

```
=COUNTIF(Books!A:A, "<>")
```

Logically, this is what I want, but it doesn't work in Excel:

```
=COUNTIF(Books!A2:A, "<>")
```

Seems like this should be simple? Am I missing something obvious? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use count to count the contents of each cell and that way you exclude the header text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilies:

1. Use the limit of Excel by entering the last possible row:

   ```
   =COUNTIF(Books!A2:A1048576;"<>")
   ```
2. If the Header is always there, you could just substract it from the result:

   ```
   =COUNTIF(Books!A:A, "<>")-1
   ```

Comment: Yeah, I'd already considered the -1 approach. Seems like the simplest solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the first row is dedicated to a title simply use the below. Easy........

For a text

=COUNTA(A:A)-1

---

For Numerics

=COUNT(A:A)-1

Answer (score -1):

You need to count until last row, so if your data finish in row 20, then:

```
=COUNTIF(Books!A2:A20, "<>")
```

But if your data change rows quantity very often sometimes 20, sometimes 40, sometimes 10, I suggest you use a Table (a Listobject) because it works as a dynamic range:

[Create and format tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-format-tables-e81aa349-b006-4f8a-9806-5af9df0ac664)

[image]

My formula is:

`=COUNTIF(Table1[Book Name],"<>")`

Where `Table1[Book Name]` equals to range A2:A9 in this case. But if you add more data, `Table1[Book Name]` will refer to new range, and the formula will autoupdate :)

[image]

Using full qualified ranges as `A:A` may work and it's easy to use but it's a waste of resources checking a million cells every time you calculate. Besides, if you use a lot of formulas using full columns, it may overcharge the file and the time recalculations needs.